# C# Console app post request - Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page

Tags: c#, http-post

Trying to do a post request to login page in C# which will do a redirect once logged in successfully. I'm getting

> Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.

Can we enable javascript in C# console app or what is the alternate solution for this? It might be old issue, but couldn't find an answer after a long search.

Comment: "Can we enable javascript in C# console app". No, but what are you trying to do? "Trying to do a post request to login page" - what login page, where? Your own app or some website?

Comment: "can we do enable javascript in c# console app" uh???? http-post has 0 notion of javascript. its pure text (or binary)

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate a so-called "headless browser"m which would get the job done, but that's not an easy solution and probably would just lead to further problems down the line. The proper solution really depends on the website you're trying to reach, how it handles the login requests, how it detects javascript, and what it uses javascript for. Have you tried if the site is usable - after login - with javascript disabled? If not, then your problem just grew - a lot. If yes, then the easiest solution is probably simulating in your code what the site you're posting to is doing.

Do you know if the login was actually succesful and it's just a display issue? Because if that#s the case, the situation is way easier to handle than if you're not.

Comment: disabled javascript in browser. and the login page is not loading, just the message "Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.  "   once I logged in and disabled JS, the site works fine. So the website seems checking only in login page, its an external website I don't have access to it.

Comment: In this case, you could try to analyse what the login javascript does, and replicate it in your app: if it only does some additional requests, you can replicate them.